# Access to Azure SQL database returns unsupported keyword “metadata” error

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App that accesses my Azure SQL Server database. Until recently (August 2020) the access worked without a problem but now it is not working. When I develop and test the app locally on my machine the read/write to the Azure SQL database is working, just not when I deploy the app to Azure.

I added the Web App’s outbound IP range to the Azure SQL Server firewall settings with no success.

I am using Entity Framework to connect to the database and want to continue doing so.

The error I get is:

"Keyword not supported: 'metadata'."
at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal

"The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString."
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString

The test that it’s working would be to visit https://www.triviaweb.net/ and see a list of players in the scoreboard.

Comment: The connection string is  <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TriviaWebModel.csdl|res://*/TriviaWebModel.ssdl|res://*/TriviaWebModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:dolaris.database.windows.net;initial catalog={dbname};persist security info=True;user id={user};password={psw};multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: Looks like its working as I can see list of players on the score board.

Comment: Problem is back. The published web.config contains a connection string inside another one. connectionString="metadata=res://*/TriviaWebModel.csdl|res://*/TriviaWebModel.ssdl|res://*/TriviaWebModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='metadata=res://*/TriviaWebModel.csdl|res://*/TriviaWebModel.ssdl|res://*/TriviaWebModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:dolaris.database.windows.net;initial catalog={cata};persist security info=True;user id={id};password={psw};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;'"

Answer (score 0):

That connection string is only supported by Entity Framework. Use the below connection string and it should work. If it doesn't then try taking off `;application name=EntityFramework` from the connection string.

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="data source=tcp:dolaris.database.windows.net;initial catalog={dbname};persist security info=True;user id={user};password={psw};multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```